# Proof help: why is the constructed field a splitting field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

Here is my books definition of a splitting field:

[image]

Note that it uses the word: **smallest:**

In the last converse part of this theorem. I see that the field E created is a field that contains F(this is by hypothesis of the theorem). And it also contains all the zeros of the given polynomials. But I do not see why it is the smallest such field? I mean, how is it ensured that we do not get any "extra" elements in our field?

The proof is from "A first course in Abstract Algebra", by John B. Fraleigh, seventh edition, chapter 50 "Splitting fields".

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the proof, consider the set $S$  of all irreducoble polynoials having at least one zero in $E$. Assume the splitting field $K$ of this set of polynomials is strictly smaller than $E$. Let $\alpha\in E\setminus K$. As $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$, there exists a polynomial $f\in F[x]$ with $f(\alpha)=0$. WE may assume wlog that $f$ is irreducible. Then $f\in S$ and hence all its roots - including $\alpha$ - are in $K$, contradiction.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just have one question, sorry for not understanding everything. Why is $\alpha$ algebraic?

Comment: @user119615 Because every element of $\overline F$ is algebraic over $F$.

Comment: But look at $\mathbb{Q}$, and $\mathbb{C}$. $\pi$ is in $\mathbb{C}$, but $\pi$ is not algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Earlier sometimes E have been an algebraic extension, is it maybe that the theorem is only valid if E is an algebraic extension?

Comment: The text says $F\le E\le\overline F$. Indeed, if $E$ were allowed to have transcendental elements, the claim might be false

Comment: Thank you, but doesn't that notation only mean that they are subfield, and extension fields of each other, not necessarily that the extensions are algebraic?