# Can it be proved that this extension is algebraic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

Assume that we have a field F, an extension field E of F, and both of them are contained in the algebraic clousure $\overline{F}$.

Let E have the property that every automorphism of $\overline{F}$ that leaves every element of F fixed, maps E onto itself.

**Does then E have to be an algebraic extension of F?**

(I am wondering about this because I think **it can be show that a splitting field is an algebraic extension?**, and I am unsure about a theorem in my book, if he sometimes just forgets to say that E is an algebraic extension, if it is not, or if it follows from something.)

Comment: Well, $E\subseteq \overline F,$ so $E/F$ is algebraic, by definition?

Comment: Indeed, that's what I meant [yesterday](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1277558/proof-help-why-is-the-constructed-field-a-splitting-field) already

Comment: Thanks @awllower I have seen someone write something similar on the site. But I do not understand this. I mean is $\overline{F}$ algebraic just befcause it is an algebraic clousure? I mean an algebraic clousre is a field that continas all the zeros of polynomials with coefficients in that field(If $f(x) \in \overline{F}[x]$, then all its zeros are in $\overline{F}$). But that doesn't mean it is an algebraic extension of the field F?

Comment: Look up "algebraic closure" again. Having roots of all polynomials in $F$ is not enough for an extension to be known as an algebraic closure. For instance, $\Bbb C$ contains all roots of polynomials in $\Bbb Q$, but we cannot say $\Bbb C$ is an algebraic closure of $\Bbb Q$. The other condition necessary for being called an algebraic closure is being an algebraic extension.

Comment: The property you  mention describes a *normal*  extension of $F$.

Comment: Ok, i may have seriously misunderstood this, I appologize for asking this question.

Comment: @PVanchinathan No, the property of having roots of all polynomials in a lower field is not normality. For instance, like I said in my comment above, $\Bbb C$ has all roots of polynomials in $\Bbb Q$, but the extension $\Bbb C/\Bbb Q$ is not normal.

Comment: @whacka PVanchinathan referred to the property in the question body.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help in clearing this up for me.